wrangling a new installation gone awry, installed on external drive
I'm new to trying to keep a Linux machine for dev work. (System76 Serval WS, Intel i9, Firmware: 2-23-9-19_16ef69c, OS: Ubuntu 24.10, Gnome 47)
TLDR: my Ubuntu install ended up on my external drive, not my local hard drive. I need a step-by-step for n00bs and idiots on how to get the install onto my local drive. I am happy to reinstall but imagine I will accidentally do the exact same thing. I have found similar questions but from years ago, with a variety of different answers yet none of the answers are explained in a way a beginner could follow. I want foolproof.
Some answers are saying I should copy my external drive to my local machine (don't know how to do that, but following the instructions)
Here's the printout of my terminal output from sudo /sbin/fdisk -l:
loop0 - loop7
nvme0n1
sda
loop8 - loop48
Disk model: Samsung SSD 990 PRO 1TB                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6FED877F-E89E-457E-8AD5-919CBE3B108F

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648 1953521663 1951318016 930.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors
Disk model: My Passport 260F
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B179BD28-94FB-423E-9F95-94A26FD3742F

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        64   11054631   11054568  5.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  11054632   11064759      10128  4.9M EFI System
/dev/sda3  11064760   11065359        600  300K Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  11067392 3906961407 3895894016  1.8T Linux filesystem

I got a top-of-the-line System76 with Ubuntu pre-installed.  Unfortunately, I left it alone for about 6 months.  When I came back to it, it would no longer boot. So, I wiped an external hard drive clean and used it to put the new LTS installer on it.  I thought it worked, but it turns out my Ubuntu install is now on the external drive.
UPDATE-RESOLVED
This is going to sound like I must have been out of my mind, but after getting prompted to boot it from the external drive a few times, for no reason I can imagine or observe, it now just boots from my native hard drive.  So, my install must have worked fine?  Then why was it booting to BusyBox?  I have no idea.

Try the following.
Start a Live Ubuntu session 24.04.1 (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=24.04.1&architecture=amd64&lts=true) NO 24.10
The upload is complete.
Open a terminal.
Run on it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gparted

Unmount /dev/sda4
sudo umount /dev/sda4

Then load gparted
sudo gparted

From Gparted, select the disk /dev/sda
Select and delete the partition /dev/sda4
Create the following partitions in the now free space:
One 1 gb Efi System
One 100 gb, ext4 for /
One   8 gb, swap for Swap, approximate (Three times the RAM is best)
One of the remaining gigs, ext4 for /home
Apply the changes
Start the installation and in partitioning choose manual.
And select the partitions for / , swap, and for /home, Grub is installed by default in (1 gb Efi System)
If you don't need MSWindows data, unmount all partitions, delete them and create Ubuntu partitions, so that you have Ubuntu as the only operating system. 24.04.1 is recommended because it is LTS, 24.10 is for testing and has very little support. Once installed, for the server it is advisable to subscribe to Ubuntu Pro, with extended updates.

Hi there, thanks for the thorough response.  "gparted" is not letting me resize my partitions.  It just doesn't allow me to reduce the size of the ext4.  And there's no room left.  I've noticed that all my Ubuntu OS is on the external hard drive and I can navigate it using the Files GUI.  Can I just copy it over and reboot or something?

Delete do not shrink /dev/sda4, if you have important data accessible copy it to an external media. if you do not use MSWindows, delete all partitions, it requires unmounting them first.

It won't let me unmount any of the drives, nor partition them, nor resize them.  Nothing is working either in the terminal as you suggested, or in the gparted gui.  I would add photos, but I don't think I can in this comment section.

If you don't have any important data on your hard drive, try wiping it from a live Ubuntu session and then creating the partition table and partitions, to do this from a terminal run:
sudo shred -n 2 -vfz /dev/sda, this will completely erase your /dev/sda drive
